# SQLCMD for windows 2003

Tags: sqlcmd, windows-2003-webserver

I need to install `SQLCMD` utility on a `windows 2003 Standard Edition SP 2 server`. I tried to install download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36433. When I try to install, it asks for `ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server`. This driver is available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36434. However this is not supported for `Windows 2003 OS`. I tried to look for the older version of `SQLCMD` utility that might use an older driver compatible with Windows 2003 server, but could not find it.

Can you pls. suggest any alternative or give any other suggestion?

Comment: I tried to download SQLCMD from feature packs 2005 and 2008, however, they both require SQL client installed on the machine as a prerequisite. Is it that SQLCMD cannot be installed without SQL client?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, solution that worked for me on my server 2003:

- First installation of sqlncli.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=16978 (you have to expand the Install instructions)
- Then installation of SqlCmdLnUtils.msi (different from MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi which failed) from the same page https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=16978